# Retrieve thumbnail url in loop

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hi I am trying to instegrate a slider into my wordpress theme.This is what I have so far:

```
<?php 
                            $slider_query = new WP_Query(array(
                                        'posts_per_page'=>'5'
                            ));

                            if($slider_query->have_posts()):
                                while($slider_query->have_posts()):
                                    $slider_query->the_post();
                                        if(function_exists('has_post_thumbnail') && has_post_thumbnail()){
                                            the_post_thumbnail();
                                        }
                                 endwhile;
                            endif;
```

?>

While this does work and retrieves the image I need to be able to retribe the url because I have to set different title attributes that are stored for the caption.

Anyone know of a way to retrieve the thumbnail url?

**EDIT:** I have also tryed to get the URL using

```
$url = wp_get_attachment_image_src(the_post_thumbnail());
```

But for som reason the query returns 10 links img's and I set it to 5 only.Wierd thing is that the even images have no source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'wanted-size' );`. (replace `wanted-size` with the correct size).

More on `get_post_thumbnail_id` [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id).

Comment: This returns an array, the `[0]`th index of which is the source ;)